# How to pass data between two child components in react js?

Tags: reactjs, function, onclick, components, parent-child

I want some suggestions on how this thing can be done, how can I pass data between two child components in react.
My code architecture is something like this:-

```
Parent 
---Child 1
---Child 2
---Child 3
```

Now I want to pass some data from child 1 to child 2.
So how it can be done and what will be the best approach for it.

This is my code sample.

Parent code:

```
import './css/style.css';
const parent = () => {
  return (
         <div>
            <Child 1 />
            <Child 2 />  
            <Child 3 />
         </div>
  );
};
export default parent;
```

So, here in child 1 I want a onClick() event which will call a method in child 2 component. How it can be done?

And I want to send data from Child 1 component to parent component. How it can be done?

Comment: Please share, what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by passing callback function to common parent component and then from parrent component to childs. Simple way for simple apps. Or also it's possible with React.Context, or state managers sush as Redux, Mobx, Mobx State tree.

Comment: If you can share some example then it would be great.

Comment: @Avanish
 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ccgsvi?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Findex.js